# How do I pass all key value pairs of a dictionary one after another in function of a class?

Tags: python, function, class

I have the following `Restaurant class that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments and keyword arguments.

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, name, location, *foods, **pizza_toppings):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.foods = list(foods)
        self.pizza_toppings = dict(pizza_toppings)


    def get_pizza_toppings(self):
        for key, value in self.pizza_toppings.items():
            print(f'The ordered toppings for your pizza is {self.pizza_toppings[key]} of {key}.' )

karoki = Restaurant('Karoki Restaurant', 'NYC 2rd rue', 'Pizza', 'Potato Chips', 'Chicken Fried Steak', sauce= '2 ounce', fromage='4 ounce', chips='3 ounce')

karoki.get_pizza_toppings()
```

the output of above code is:

```
The ordered toppings for your pizza is 2 ounce of sauce.
The ordered toppings for your pizza is 4 ounce of fromage.
The ordered toppings for your pizza is 3 ounce of chips.
```

this is not the ideal output I am looking for. I want to modify `get_pizza_toppings()` method as such that it outputs something like this:

```
The ordered toppings for your pizza is 2 ounce of sauce, 4 ounce of fromage and 3 ounce of chips.
```

I mused a lot how to do this, but couldn't. Hence, please help me with it thank you?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want. Please show us the expected output and how you want to call `get_pizza_toppings()`.

Comment: @buhtz i explained what I am looking for. I included the expected output and how I want to call it

Comment: I have not downvoted but the quality of your question is low. You did not use correct upper case letters in your text. You did not provide a minimal working example (copy & paste your code does not work). Also your code is not minimal. There could be less lines to describe your problem.

Comment: @buhtz you're right this code could be minimal, didn't thought about that yet and English is not my first language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve it to append part of the string like `2 ounce of sauce` etc within the loop, and appending the last `(key,value)` pair in a special manner (`and` in front of the string and a `.` at the end)

```
def get_pizza_toppings(self):

    # Initial string
    s = f'The ordered toppings for your pizza is '

    # Iterate over the dictionary via enumerate
    for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(self.pizza_toppings.items()):

        # For the last element, change the string slightly
        if idx == len(self.pizza_toppings) - 1:
            s += f'and {self.pizza_toppings[key]} of {key}. '

        # Get rid of extra comma at second last item of dictionary
        elif idx == (len(self.pizza_toppings.keys())-2):
            s += f'{self.pizza_toppings[key]} of {key} '

        # Else append string the normal way
        else:
            s += f'{self.pizza_toppings[key]} of {key}, '

    print(s)
```

The output will be

```
The ordered toppings for your pizza is 2 ounce of sauce, 4 ounce of fromage and 3 ounce of chips.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print a constant string before, and then loop over items like you did; however, you need to find out which element is the last (for 'and' and '.' elems).

```
def get_pizza_toppings(self):
    string_to_print = 'The ordered toppings for your pizza is '
    last_key = list(self.pizza_toppings.keys())[-1]

    for key, value in self.pizza_toppings.items():
        if key is last_key:
            string_to_print += 'and {0} of {1}.'.format(value, key)
        else:
            string_to_print += '{0} of {1}, '.format(value, key)

    print(string_to_print)
```

Comment: Please provide a discription to your code. Code only does not help.

Comment: He asked for an output, I gave him the code to achieve that. Is it a reason for downvoting? Meh

Comment: @Meh Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and keep in mind that 10 years later your answer should help someone.

Comment: Did you try to run this code? The line `if key is self.pizza_toppings.keys()[-1]:` will throw an `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable` error